# Show entries where relationship field equals Yes with the Query

Tags: relationships, query, channel-images, sql

I have 2 channels, one called artists and another called gallery.
In the artists channel there is a checkbox to say if the artist has given permission for their work to be shown.
In the gallery channel I have the artwork related to an artist entry from the artist channel using  the native EE relationship field.

I want to output all the gallery entries where the related artists has the channel field 'artist_copyright' set to 'Yes'.

I can't see how I can do this using Channel Entries, is this possible using the Query module, if so what is the query I should use?

I want to output a Channel Images field along with other custom fields

Comment: Just to confirm, the way you have it set up now is that the "yes" is a broad approval for the artists' work to be shown and not a per-artwork permission?

Comment: @JeanSt-Amand That is correct.